# bat файл для параллельного запуска программы в разных потоках

Tags: windows, сортировка, cmd, bat

Доброго времени суток. Стоит такая задача.

Имеется программа, написанная на Java. Её запуск осуществляется следующим образом:

`java Main 0 7`

Причём программа должна отработать потом на параметрах `8 15`, `16 23` и т.д. до `233 240`. Программа в ходе работы выводит на консоль некоторые строки. Необходимо автоматизировать процесс запуска данной программы. Запускать одновременно программу на `16` потоках с параметрами `0 7`, `8 15`, `16 23`, `24 31` и т.д., записать их результаты работы в один текстовый файл, отсортировать его, убрать дубликаты. Заново запустить одновременно 16 экземпляров, повторить то же самое и так до тех пор, пока не будет выполнен экземпляр с параметрами `233 240`.

Answer (score 1):

Для параллельного запуска программ можно использовать команду start. Например, если в bat-файл ввести:

```
start notepad 1.txt
start notepad 2.txt
start notepad 3.txt
```

то откроется три окна Notepad c файлами 1, 2 и 3. Если просто написать

```
notepad 1.txt
notepad 2.txt
notepad 3.txt
```

То 2-й откроется только после закрытия 1-го.